Does incrementing the number of plays $n$ of a machine $i$ with max $\nu(i,n)$ value always yield the same values for $\min_{k_j}\max_j\nu(j,k_j)$?
I am struggling with a problem that seems quite basic, but I don't know how to solve it.
Consider a real valued function $\nu(i,n)$ on $\{1,\ldots,d\}\times\mathbb{N}$.
Displayed as a "matrix" this looks like
\begin{equation*}
\begin{matrix}
\nu(1,0)&\nu(1,1)&\nu(1,2)&\nu(1,3)&\cdots
\\
\nu(2,0)&\nu(2,1)&\nu(2,2)&\nu(2,3)&\cdots
\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots
\\
\nu(d,0)&\nu(d,1)&\nu(d,2)&\nu(d,3)&\cdots
\end{matrix}
\end{equation*}
Think of the vertical dimension as machines $i=1,\ldots,d$,
and the horizontal one as the number of plays.
So $\nu(i,n)$ is the function value for machine $i$ when it has been played $n$ times.
I start at time $t=0$ with the values in the left "column":
\begin{equation*}
\begin{matrix}
\nu(1,0)
\\
\nu(2,0)
\\
\vdots
\\
\nu(d,0)
\end{matrix}
\end{equation*}
For (at least) one machine $i$ the value $\nu(i,0)$ will be maximal, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
\nu(i,0) = \max_{j=1,\ldots,d}\nu(j,0),
\end{equation*}
and this is the machine that I play next,
yielding at time $t=1$ the values
\begin{equation*}
\begin{matrix}
\nu(1,0)
\\
\vdots
\\
\nu(i,1)
\\
\vdots
\\
\nu(d,0)
\end{matrix}
\end{equation*}
This way of choosing a machine to play next is repeated indefinitely,
resulting for each time $t$ in the "update rule"
\begin{equation*}
\begin{matrix}
\nu(1,n_1)
\\
\vdots
\\
\nu(i,n_i)
\\
\vdots
\\
\nu(d,n_d)
\end{matrix}
\quad\mapsto\quad
\begin{matrix}
\nu(1,n_1)
\\
\vdots
\\
\nu(i,n_i + 1)
\\
\vdots
\\
\nu(d,n_d)
\end{matrix}
\quad\text{for some $i$ with }\quad
\nu(i,n_i) = \max_{j=1,\ldots,d}\nu(j,n_j),
\end{equation*}
where $n_1,\ldots,n_d$ are the number of times that machines $1,\ldots,d$ have been played at time $t$.
This "update rule" is known as an "index policy".
Index policies in general are not unique,
because at any time there may be more than one machine $i$
with a maximal value for $\nu(i,n_i)$.
Question:
If two different index policies at a time $t$
result in a number of plays
$m_1,\ldots,m_d$ respectively $n_1,\ldots,n_d$
of the machines $1,\ldots,d$,
does for them the equality
\begin{equation*}
\min_{\substack{0\leq k_1\leq m_1\\ \vdots\\ 0\leq k_d\leq m_d}}
\max_{j=1,\ldots,d}
\nu(j,k_j)
=
\min_{\substack{0\leq k_1\leq n_1\\ \vdots\\ 0\leq k_d\leq n_d}}
\max_{j=1,\ldots,d}
\nu(j,k_j)
\end{equation*}
hold?
In words, does maximizing over the machines followed by minimizing over the number of plays so far result in the same value,
regardless of the index policy followed?
According to the literature
(e.g. page 134, equation (2.7) in Mandelbaum (1986) in the context of multi-armed bandits)
the answer is "yes",
but I only manage to show this for simple cases.
How to show this in general?
I believe that I can interchange the $\min$ and $\max$ operations
in the evaluated quantity according to the identity
\begin{equation*}
\min_{\substack{0\leq k_1\leq n_1\\ \vdots\\ 0\leq k_d\leq n_d}}
\max_{j=1,\ldots,d}
\nu(j,k_j)
=
\max_{j=1,\ldots,d}
\min_{0\leq k_j\leq n_j}
\nu(j,k_j)
\end{equation*}
which may simplify notation a bit.
Motivation:
The above problem appears as a subproblem in the solution of the basic  multi-armed bandit problem,
where the index process $\nu_i$ is the Gittins index of machine $i$.
However, I don't think this context is required for the solution of the above problem.
In the context of multi-armed bandits,
Mandelbaum (1986) does not go into details why the answer to the above problem is "yes".
He then uses this result to show that index policies are optimal policies for the multi-armed bandit problem.

Are the rewards Markovian ? Are you assuming $d$- independent one-armed bandits or one multi-armed bandit etc ? The rule you are describing just sounds like a purely greedy strategy. If the rewards are stochastic, then you can only expect to have these equalities in terms of "value functions" from classic MDP - like in expectation ?
Also, I am not understanding your question. When you say at time $t$, it actually sounds like two different index policies starting from $t=0$ and ending at time $t$, the way you worded.

The reward need not be Markovian. The arms/machines are independent. But I stripped away these underlying details because I'm under the impression that they're not actually relevant for the described problem where the Gittins indices $\nu_i$ are considered. In fact I think the problem still stands when things are deterministic. The described strategy, called "index policy", need not be unique. So I want to know if two different index policies yield the same values for $\nu$ maximized over machines and minimized over plays so far.

in your "update rule", for example $t=1$, $\nu(i,1)$ is what exactly ?

It is the Gittins index of machine $1$ after $1$ plays. But this interpretation I think is not necessary, $\nu$ could be any abstract function.

Sorry, I meant machine $i$, not $1$.
